# What is the cardinality of the set of injective functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathcal P \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals, infinity

**Question**

> What is the cardinality of the set of injective functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathcal P \mathbb{N}$?

**Attempt**

If we denote the desired set as $I$, then we can find an upper bound by dropping the requirement for injectivity as follows:

$$|I| \leq |\mathcal P \mathbb{N}|^{|\mathbb{N}|} = (2^{\aleph _0})^{\aleph _0} = 2^{\aleph _0}$$

However, I am struggling to find a suitable lower bound. It is quite easy to show that the set must be greater than or equal to $\aleph _0$ by constructing a function that maps natural numbers to sets containing only themselves. Although, I need to construct an injection from $\mathcal P \mathbb{N}$ into $I$ in order to show that $2^{\aleph _0}$ is also a lower bound.

After this point, we can simply invoke [Cantor-Schrdoder-Bernstein Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem), to conclude that $|I| = 2 ^{\aleph _0}$.

---

I have read that the following is an injective map that provides the desired lower bound:

$$ g(X) = n \mapsto \begin{cases}
\text{ {$n+1$}}  & \text{if $n \in X$} \\
\text{ {$0,\space n+1$}} & \text{if $n \not \in X$}
\end{cases}$$

However, I am hoping for a more intuitive solution that I could construct myself (if the above solution can be explained in an intuitive way, then I am also happy for that to be provided as a valid solution to the question). This was a former exam problem, so I was hoping to be able to understand the solution in a way that will allow me to construct functions of my own in similar examples.

I would be grateful for any assistance here.

Comment: An infinite set has uncountably many infinite countable subsets.

Comment: This is not a result I am allowed to quote without a proof, so I assume it would just be quicker to find an injection (unless the proof of the result you mention is short?) @ArturoMagidin

Comment: If you have an injection from $\{2,3,4,\dots\}$, then you have an uncountable number of choices for where to map $1$.

Comment: AC doesn't prove that (you would need CH, not AC). But here you can map $n$ to $\{n\}$ for $n\geq 2$, and then how many different ways can you pick the image of $1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, construct an injection $f:\mathbb N\to\mathcal P(\mathcal N)$. Let $a_n=f(n)$ and let $A=\{a_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$.

For each $x\in\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ we shall define an injection $h_x:\mathbb N\to\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ such that $h_x(1)=x$, thus showing that the set of injections from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ has cardinality at least as great as the cardinality of $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$.

If $x=a_1$ let $h_x=f$.

If $x\notin A$ let $h_x(1)=x$ and $h_x(n)=a_n$ for $n\ne1$.

If $x=a_k\in A\setminus\{a_1\}$ let $h_x(1)=x$, $h_x(k)=a_1$, and $h_x(n)=a_n$ for $n\notin\{1,k\}$.

Answer (score 2):

For $g\in\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ we can define the singleton-valued function $f_g(n)=\{g(1)+\cdots+g(n)\}$.

Comment: It exhibits $\mathfrak{c}$-many injective functions $f_g:\Bbb N\to{\cal P}(\Bbb N)$, because there are ${\frak c}=2^{\aleph_0}$-many functions $g:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$.